# struct as an argument of sucessive functions... little error need fixing. (C)

Tags: c, pointers, struct

So I got that:

```
typedef struct {
    int score;
    char init;
} Student;

int changestuff(Student *students) {

    students->score = 100;

    students++;

    students->score = 200;

    changestuffagain(students);

}

int changestuffagain(Student *students) {

     students->score = 100;

    students++;

    students->score = 200;
}

int main() {

    Student students[2];

    changestuff(students);


}
```

I call the function changestuff and it modifiys correctly the socre of players[0] and players[1], but my little problem, is that when I call the second function changestuffagain, the argument does not pass players[0] and players[1], it passes just players[1] (the value of players at the moment of calling changestuffagain)

How i could fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's what you told it to do. When your `changestuff` function calls `changestuffagain`, you've incremented the value of `students`, so it now points to the second `Student` in the array. If you want to keep the pointer in the same place, you should pass the non-incremented value.

Comment: so the only way is to decrease it before calling the second function?

Comment: @user3027143 just use `students[0]` and `stunders[1]` in changestuff etc instead of incrementing the pointer.

Comment: well thats too a good idea, if I use the position explicitly i should use players[0].score or players[0]->score?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `students++` you jump to the next memory position where it is allocated a `Student`(in your case `students[1]`). You could decrement `students` before making the call of `changestuffagain()`.

For example:

```
students--;
changestuffagain(students);
```